# BeautifulSoup getting all links after given tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape the following pages (e.g [1](http://www.transitbangkok.com/showBestRoute.php?from=Sutthawat+-+Arun+Amarin+Intersection&to=Sukhumvit&originSelected=true&destinationSelected=true&lang=en), [2](http://www.transitbangkok.com/showBestRoute.php?from=Wang+Lang+Pier+%28Tha+Prachan%29&to=Sanam+Pao&originSelected=false&destinationSelected=false&lang=en)) using `BeautifulSoup` to get list of actions to travel from one place in Bangkok to another place.

Basically, I can query and select the description of the trips as follows.

```
url = 'http://www.transitbangkok.com/showBestRoute.php?from=Sutthawat+-+Arun+Amarin+Intersection&to=Sukhumvit&originSelected=true&destinationSelected=true&lang=en'
route_request = requests.get(url)
soup_route = BeautifulSoup(route_request.content, 'lxml')
descriptions = soup_route.find('div', attrs={'id': 'routeDescription'})
```

The HTML of `descriptions` looks like the following

```
<div id="routeDescription">
...
<br/>
<img src="/images/walk_icon_small.PNG" style="vertical-align:middle;padding-right: 10px;margin-right: 0px;"/>Walk by foot to <b>Sanam Luang</b>
<br/>
<img src="/images/bus_icon_semi_small.gif" style="vertical-align:middle;padding-right: 10px;margin-right: 0px;"/>Travel to <b>Khok Wua</b> using the line(s): <b><a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/2">2</a></b> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/15">15</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/44">44</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/47">47</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/59">59</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/201">201</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/203">203</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/512">512</a><br/>
...
</div>
```

Basically, I try to get list of actions and bus lines to travel to the next location (question updated with the answer but still didn't solve).

```
route_descrtions = []
for description in descriptions.find_all('img'):
    action = description.next_sibling
    to_station = action.next_sibling
    n = action.find_next_siblings('a')
    if 'travel' in action.lower():
        lines = [to_station.find_next('b').text] +  [a.contents[0] for a in n]
    else:
        lines = []
    desp = {'action': action,
            'to': to_station.text,
            'lines': lines}
    route_descrtions.append(desp)
```

However, I don't know how to loop through links after each action (`Travel to` action) and append to my list. I tried `find_next('a')` and `find_next_siblings('a')` but didn't achieve my task.

**Output**

```
[{'action': 'Walk by foot to ', 'lines': [], 'to': 'Wang Lang (Siriraj)'},
 {'action': 'Travel to ',
  'lines': ['Chao Phraya Express Boat', '40', '48', '501', '508'],
  'to': 'Si Phraya'},
 {'action': 'Walk by foot to ', 'lines': [], 'to': 'Sheraton Royal Orchid'},
 {'action': 'Travel to ',
  'lines': ['16', '40', '48', '501', '508'],
  'to': 'Siam'},
 {'action': 'Travel to ',
  'lines': ['BTS - Sukhumvit', '40', '48', '501', '508'],
  'to': 'Asok'},
 {'action': 'Walk by foot to ', 'lines': [], 'to': 'Sukhumvit'}]
```

**Desired output**

```
[{'action': 'Walk by foot to ', 'lines': [], 'to': 'Wang Lang (Siriraj)'},
 {'action': 'Travel to ',
  'lines': ['Chao Phraya Express Boat'],
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint

url = 'http://www.transitbangkok.com/showBestRoute.php?from=Sutthawat+-+Arun+Amarin+Intersection&to=Sukhumvit&originSelected=true&destinationSelected=true&lang=en'
route_request = requests.get(url)
soup_route = BeautifulSoup(route_request.content, 'lxml')
routes = soup_route.find('div', attrs={'id': 'routeDescription'})

parsed_routes = list()
for img in routes.find_all('img'):
    action = img.next_sibling
    to_station = action.next_sibling
    links = list()
    for sibling in img.next_siblings:
        if sibling.name == 'a':
            links.append(sibling)
        elif sibling.name == 'img':
            break

    lines = list()
    if 'travel' in action.lower():
        lines.extend([to_station.find_next('b').text])
        lines.extend([link.contents[0] for link in links])

    parsed_route = {'action': action, 'to': to_station.text, 'lines': lines}
    parsed_routes.append(parsed_route)

pprint.pprint(parsed_routes)
```

This outputs:

```
[{'action': 'Walk by foot to ', 'lines': [], 'to': 'Wang Lang (Siriraj)'},
 {'action': 'Travel to ',
  'lines': ['Chao Phraya Express Boat'],
  'to': 'Si Phraya'},
 {'action': 'Walk by foot to ', 'lines': [], 'to': 'Sheraton Royal Orchid'},
 {'action': 'Travel to ', 'lines': ['16'], 'to': 'Siam'},
 {'action': 'Travel to ',
  'lines': ['BTS - Sukhumvit', '40', '48', '501', '508'],
  'to': 'Asok'},
 {'action': 'Walk by foot to ', 'lines': [], 'to': 'Sukhumvit'}]
```

Your key issue was `n = action.find_next_siblings('a')` because it got all the links at the same level after your "current" image. Seeing as all the images and all the links were at the same level, this wasn't what you wanted.

You probably were thinking of the images as parent nodes to the links. Something like:

- img1

  - link1
- img2

  - link2
- img3

  - link3
  - link4
  - link5

However, in reality it was more like the following:

- img1
- link1
- img2
- link2
- img3
- link3
- link4
- link5

When you asked for images you got img1, img2, and img3 (in this example). And when you asked for all next link siblings you got that. So if you were at img2, and asked for the next link siblings you got them, i.e.,

- img1
- link1
- img2 < You're here, and got ...
- **link2** < This,
- img3 - (not this, because it isn't a link)
- **link3** < this,
- **link4** < this, and
- **link5** < this

I hope that explains. The change I did was to just loop until you find an image and stop there. Thus your outer image loop continues from there. I also cleaned up some of the code. Just for clarity.

Comment: Thanks Andre! the solution works for me. Also thanks for the great explanation. Already accepted the answer (and thumbs up)!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find_next_siblings` (using Python 2.7):

```
import bs4

text = '''<img src="/images/bus_icon_semi_small.gif" style="vertical-align:middle;padding-right: 10px;margin-right: 0px;"/>Travel to <b>Khok Wua</b> using the line(s): <b><a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/2">2</a></b> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/15">15</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/44">44</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/47">47</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/59">59</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/201">201</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/203">203</a> or <a href="lines/bangkok-bus-line/512">512</a><br/>x`x'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
img = soup.find('img')
action = img.next_sibling
to_station = action.next_sibling
n = to_station.find_next_siblings('a')
d = {
    'action': action,
    'to': to_station.text,
    'buses': [a.contents[0] for a in n]
}
```

Results:

```
{'action': u'Travel to ', 'to': u'Khok Wua', 'buses': [u'15', u'44', u'47', u'59', u'201', u'203', u'512']}
```

Comment: Hi Yohanes, I tried it but it doesn't work for my particular problem. Do you have the solution that works for the given full HTML too?